# Give unique key props to react nested map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

How to give a unique key props in react map. I use uuidv4 library but react also says every child component should have a unique key prop.
This is my code that I use uuidv4 npm library.

I try many ways but it not work.

```
    // import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar'
  import React from 'react'
  import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
  import ButtonGroup from '../components/ButtonGroup';
  import MCQS from '../components/MCQ';
  import { Outlet } from 'react-router';
  import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
  import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
  const C_P_HOME = () => {
    const { heading } = useSelector(state => state.heading);
    const { questions } = useSelector(state => state.question);
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar isContainerTrue={false} />
        <div className='grid grid-cols-12 '>
          <div className="col-span-6 bg-slate-100 grid grid-cols-12 p-8 h-screen items-baseline">
            <ButtonGroup />
            <Outlet />
          </div>
          <div className="col-span-6 bg-slate-200 h-screen overflow-y-scroll">
            <div className="heading select-none">
              <h1 className='text-2xl text-center font-bold mt-8'>{heading}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="questions p-8">

              {
                questions.map((q, index) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <h2 className='text-2xl font-semibold' key={uuidv4()}>Q:{(index + 1) + " " + q.heading}</h2>
                      <ol className='list-[lower-roman]' key={uuidv4()}>
                        {
                          q.questions.map((ques, index) => {
                            return (
                              <>
                                <li className='text-lg ml-16' key={uuidv4()}>{ques}</li>
                              </>
                            )
                          })
                        }
                      </ol>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

  export default C_P_HOME;
```

This is the screenshot of my error.

[image: This is the screenshot of my error]

Thanks I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code. I created keys using index and the content of question.

```
 {
    questions.map((q, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={`${index}_${JSON.stringify(q)}`}>
                <h2 className='text-2xl font-semibold'>
                    Q:{index + 1 + ' ' + q.heading}
                </h2>
                <ol className='list-[lower-roman]'>
                    {q.questions.map((ques, i) => (
              <li className='text-lg ml-16' key={`${ques}_${i}`}>
                {ques}
              </li>
                        ))}
                </ol>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try.9

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here

```
 q.questions.map((ques, index) => {
                            return (
                              <>
                                <li className='text-lg ml-16' key={uuidv4()}>{ques}</li>
                              </>
                            )
```

key attribute needs to be on the container element inside `map`

just remove `<> </>`

```
 q.questions.map((ques, index) => <li className='text-lg ml-16' key={uuidv4()}>{ques}</li>)
```

or use `React.Fragment`

```
 q.questions.map((ques, index) => {
                            return (
                              <React.Fragment key={uuidv4()}>
                                <li className='text-lg ml-16' >{ques}</li>
                              </React.Fragment>
                            )
```

Comment: you never want to generate keys on the fly like it is done here (and in the question above). those will cause unwanted new instance creations because the key will change at unwanted times.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the keys when looping over an array etc. should come from each item in the array itself. assuming your `question` has an `id`, you want to use that `id` as a `key`. since an id is usually unique, this key won't change for the item unless it is f.ex. removed

Comment: I understand but can you explain how to give unique id in nested map loop.

Comment: does your question object have an id? if yes use that. if not you can use the index but its not recommended.

Comment: like this: `<div key={...}>` pass the key into the `...`

Comment: It is not static data. This object is created by user. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: I also pass key but react says give unique key props

Comment: you need the key at the top level. instead of using `<></>` you can use `<Fragment key={...}>` to wrap your `ol` and `h2` etc.